# Sqlite column keeps combining the column name and the data type as the final column name

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My column name for the sqlite database is "name" but when I go to get data from the database the column name seems to be "nameTEXT" even though there's a space between name and TEXT in my SQL declaration for the table name.

EDIT-------

My Create Table statement is

```
String CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INVENTORY + "(" + KEY_PD_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_PD_PRICE + " DECIMAL(10,2)," + KEY_PD_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + ")";
   Log.d("SQL STATEMENT", CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE);
```

Comment: Can you show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: What you get in Log.d("SQL STATEMENT") ?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the logs, I even went and deleted the created database from the device using DDMS but still no Log output.

Comment: Whoops, turns out I had to restart the emulator in order for the file deletion to take effect and run the Create method. Sorry for the time waster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the old database files from the device and changed the onCreate method to use variables as column names and when I restarted the emulator the problem seemed to have gone away. Chalking this up to human error.